# Apache home page redirection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

Hi guys I recently downloaded an open source code called ribbot from here https://github.com/barmstrong/ribbot. I have made it run lcoally and am trying to release it on an apache linux base server.

I have it installed on stories.rayku.com, but every time I go to the URL, it redirects me to rayku.com/forums (should be stories.rayku.com). Do you know how I can resolve this? This is what I have in my apache config file:

```
<VirtualHost 69.167.183.165:80>
  ServerName stories.rayku.com
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

It works fine when I visit the ip address http://69.167.183.165:8080, and redirects to rayku.com/forums when I visit stories.rayku.com

Thanks!